# Stateful testing gives hypothesis.errors.Flaky: Run failed initially but succeeded on a second try

Tags: pytest, python-hypothesis

I am trying to solve a puzzle using Hypothesis similar to what has been done here:

http://nchammas.com/writing/how-not-to-die-hard-with-hypothesis

Unfortunately it fails intermittently with the Flaky error and I am not able to track down the problem using pdb.

My program source is at:

https://gist.github.com/sureshvv/0fb78ef221fb8c1ed85dd034c83abefa

It can be run using py.test.

Any assistance to diagnose and solve the problem appreciated.

Comment: Tried to reproduce but could not see any error when I ran your code: https://gist.github.com/c3fcc74398981fdf14cff8ce9a0ba77f
I use python 3.6, py.test 3.1.1, hypothesis 3.11.1

Comment: I have since fixed it. The problem was caused by calling random.samole inside my rule rather than using st.choices. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused because of calling random.sample inside my rule. Need to use the strategies.choices() instead.

Comment: can we have strategies,sample() to provide a list of choices similar to random.sample?